# Stop excel automatically applying wrap text to copied over data

Tags: excel, vba

The problem here is whenever I copy and paste data from one worksheet into another, the copied over data cells would apply wrap text to itself automatically. How do I stop this behavior from happening?

The script is really simple.

```
Sub TestScript()
    Dim ActiveWB As Workbook
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim WS2 As Worksheet

    Set ActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WS1 = ActiveWB.Worksheets(1)
    Set WS2 = ActiveWB.Worksheets(2)

    WS1.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    WS2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    WS2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

I used xlCellTypeVisible as I am copying over filtered data from the first worksheet.

First worksheet data:

[image: First worksheet data]

Second worksheet data:

[image: Second worksheet data]

The data I am working on is just some regular tabulated data. The header row of the data has wrap text applied to it before being copied over, but for the rest of the cells I just want to copy over the number formats, font style, color fill etc. but it applies wrap text to all the data automatically. Is there an option to stop excel from doing this when copying?

Comment: You don't want Wraptext anywhere on the second sheet where you are copying the Data ?

Comment: For that add a line `WS2.UsedRange.WrapText = False` in the End of your Code

Comment: No. I would like the second sheet to follow exactly the same formatting as the first. In the first sheet, only the header row is formatted with wrap text. When copying over to the second sheet, all the cells are formatted with wrap text. I just want to stop that from happening.

Comment: then Identify the Range you are pasting your Data in and Apply the above mentioned formula with that identified range instead of UsedRange